# What this "#" is doing here

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I came up with a code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
   int i = 1427;
   double d = 1427.0;

   printf("%#o\n", i);
   printf("%#X\n", i);
   printf("\n%g\n", d);
   printf("%#g\n", d);
   return 0;
}
```

which is giving the output:

```
02623
0X593

1427
1427.00
```

First I thought `#` is used for prefixing `0` to the output but I was wrong because of its strange behavior in last output in which it is printing zeroes after decimal.
Could someone explain what this `#`is and what it is doing here?

Comment: Yes, the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) of `printf()` has an excellent explanation.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Comments are for question clarification, not engaging in meta discussions.  There's a site for that, or use chat.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#` flag has a different behavior, depending on context.

If it is used with the `o`, `x`, or `X` specifiers, the value is preceded with `0`, `0x`, or `0X` respectively.

If it is used with `a`/`A`, `e`/`E`, `f`/`F`, or `G`, the value always ends with a decimal point.

This behavior is quite well documented multiple places on the web. Searching for "printf" and possibly "format specifiers" will generally turn up lots of good links. Here are a few to whet your appetite:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx

Comment: @Cody Gray; Thanks dude. You have provided really good links(specially [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aky45ct.aspx) one helped a lot). I did't even knew that it is a flag!!!

Answer (score 1):

From the POSIX man pages `man 3p printf`:

> #:      Specifies  that  the  value is to be converted to an alternative form.  For o conversion, it increases the precision (if necessary) to force
>                 the first digit of the result to be zero. For x or X conversion specifiers, a non-zero result shall have 0x (or 0X) prefixed to it.  For  a,
>                 A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversion specifiers, the result shall always contain a radix character, even if no digits follow the radix charac‐
>                 ter. Without this flag, a radix character appears in the result of these conversions only if a digit follows it.  For  g  and  G  conversion
>                 specifiers,  trailing  zeros  shall  not  be removed from the result as they normally are.  For other conversion specifiers, the behavior is
>                 undefined.

Putting it simple: it prints the alternative format, whatever it is. For hex. values, it is prefixing `0x`, for octal `0`, and for floating points, it forces some decimal rules...

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you read about C's printf function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), you'll be able to further understand things such as "#", among others.

> Used with o, x or X specifiers the value is preceeded with 0, 0x or 0X
>   respectively for values different than zero. Used with a, A, e, E, f,
>   F, g or G it forces the written output to contain a decimal point even
>   if no more digits follow. By default, if no digits follow, no decimal
>   point is written.

Answer (score 1):

Exerpt from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders):

> #  Alternate form. For 'g' and 'G', trailing zeros are not removed. For 'f', 'F', 'e', 'E', 'g', 'G', the output always contains a decimal point. For 'o', 'x', and 'X', a 0, 0x, and 0X, respectively, is prepended to non-zero numbers.

Answer (score 0):

%#o (Octal) 0 prefix inserted.

%#x (Hex)   0x prefix added to non-zero values.

%#X (Hex)   0X prefix added to non-zero values.

%#g         Always show the decimal point trailing 
              zeros not removed.

Zeroes are bound to come after decimal because you are using %#g.